# How can you check if a field exists in a section, not by entry?

Tags: sections

For a plugin, I need to check if a certain field exists in a section. How can i manage that? I'm using the settings section from the plugin, looping through all sections by `craft()->sections->getAllSections()` and in the template with the following code:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    {% if section['specificfield'] is not defined %}
        do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how to check correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to `getEntryTypes()` from your section and then access the `getFieldLayout()` to get to the `getFields()` (thanks again @Khalwat!). Example:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    {% if section.getEntryTypes()[0].getFieldLayout().getFields()[0].getField().handle == 'specificfield' %}
        do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice though that I specifically search for the first occurances, in (most) other cases you should `foreach` the `getEntryTypes()` and `getFields()`